# What or where is the series expansion of the function $\ln\bigl(\frac{\tan x}{x}-1\bigr)$ or $\ln(\tan x-x)$ around $x=0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, computational-number-theory, power-series, taylor-series

It is known that
\begin{equation*}
\tan x=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^{2k}\bigl(2^{2k}-1\bigr)}{(2k)!}|B_{2k}|x^{2k-1}, \quad |x|<\frac{\pi}{2}
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
\ln\tan x=\ln x+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^{2k}\bigl(2^{2k-1}-1\bigr)}{k(2k)!}|B_{2k}|x^{2k}, \quad 0<x<\frac{\pi}{2},
\end{equation*}
where $B_{2k}$ denotes the classical Bernoulli numbers. From the second series expansion, we acquire
\begin{equation*}
\ln\frac{\tan x}{x}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^{2k}\bigl(2^{2k-1}-1\bigr)}{k(2k)!}|B_{2k}|x^{2k}, \quad |x|<\frac{\pi}{2}.
\end{equation*}
My question is:

What and where is the series expansion of the function $\ln\bigl(\frac{\tan x}{x}-1\bigr)$ or $\ln(\tan x-x)$ around $x=0$?

References

1. I. S. Gradshteyn and I. M. Ryzhik, *Table of Integrals, Series, and Products*, Translated from the Russian, Translation edited and with a preface by Daniel Zwillinger and Victor Moll, Eighth edition, Revised from the seventh edition, Elsevier/Academic Press, Amsterdam, 2015; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-12-384933-5.00013-8.

Comment: Equivalently, what is the series expansion of the function $$\ln\frac{3(\tan x-x)}{x^3}=\ln\biggl[\frac{3}{x^2}\biggl(\frac{\tan x}{x}-1\biggr)\biggr]$$ around $x=0$ for $|x|<\frac{\pi}{2}$?

Comment: The first several terms are $3 \log(x) - \log(3) + \frac{2 x^2}{5}+\frac{43 x^4}{525}+\frac{524 x^6}{23625}+\frac{40897 x^8}{6063750}+\frac{19393844 x^{10}}{8868234375}+\cdots$. Any computer algebra system can compute lots more terms.  (I typed `Series[Log[Tan[x] - x], {x, 0, 10}]` in Mathematica.) Do you have any reason to believe that there is a better answer than this?

Comment: @DavidESpeyer Yes, you are right: any computer algebra system can compute lots more terms. I can do that by Wolfram Mathematica too. I did that already. But I cannot write out the expression (formula) of the general term for the coefficients of the series expansion of the function $\ln(\tan x-x)$, or $\ln\bigl(\frac{\tan x}{x}-1\bigr)$, or $\ln\frac{3(\tan x-x)}{x^3}=\ln\bigl[\frac{3}{x^2}\bigl(\frac{\tan x}{x}-1\bigr)\bigr]$ around $x=0$. Can you please?

Comment: I can't, but I have no reason to expect that there is a closed formula. The Taylor series of a randomly chosen function usually doesn't have one.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer I think that the general term of the coefficients in the Maclaurin series expansion of any one of the functions mentioned here has a closed-form formula (expression) , because all the derivatives of the function $\ln\frac{3(\tan x-x)}{x^3}$, for example, $$\biggl[\ln\frac{3(\tan x-x)}{x^3}\biggr]'=\frac{3 \tan x-x \sec ^2x-2 x}{x (x-\tan x)},$$ are all elementary functions and are analytic at $x=0$.

Comment: Yue-Wu Li, Feng Qi, and Wei-Shih Du, Two forms for Maclaurin power series expansion of logarithmic expression involving tangent function, Symmetry, vol. 15 (2023), no. 9, Article 1686, 18 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.3390/sym15091686

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=\begin{cases}
\ln\dfrac{\tan x-x}{x^3}, & 0<|x|<\dfrac{\pi}{2};\\
-\ln3, & x=0.
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
Then the even function $f(x)$ has the Maclaurin power series expansion
\begin{equation}\label{ln-tan-x-cubic-ser-expans}
\begin{aligned}
f(x)&=-\ln3-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{3^{2k}D_{2k}}{(2k)!}x^{2k}\\
&=-\ln3+\frac{2 x^2}{5}+\frac{43 x^4}{525}+\frac{524 x^6}{23625}+\frac{40897 x^8}{6063750} +\frac{19393844 x^{10}}{8868234375}+\dotsm
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
for $|x|<\frac{\pi}{2}$, where
\begin{align*}
D_{2k}&=\begin{vmatrix}
0 & Q_0 & 0 & \dotsm&0& 0& 0\\
Q_1 & 0 & Q_0 & \dotsm& 0&0& 0\\
0 & Q_1 & 0 & \dotsm& 0& 0&0\\
\dotsm & \dotsm & \dotsm & \ddots&\dotsm& \dotsm& \dotsm\\
Q_{k-1} & 0 & \binom{2k-3}{1}Q_{k-2} & \dotsm& 0 & Q_0 & 0\\
0 & Q_{k-1} & 0 & \dotsm& \binom{2k-2}{2k-4}Q_1 & 0 & Q_0\\
Q_{k} & 0 & \binom{2k-1}{1}Q_{k-1} & \dotsm& 0 & \binom{2k-1}{2k-3}Q_1 & 0
\end{vmatrix}\\
&=\begin{vmatrix}
e_{i,j}
\end{vmatrix}_{2k\times2k}, \quad k\ge1,\\
e_{i,j}&=\begin{cases}
0, & (i,j)=(2\ell-1,1),\quad 1\le\ell\le k;\\
Q_\ell, & (i,j)=(2\ell,1),\quad 1\le\ell\le k;\\
0, & 1\le i\le j-2\le2k-2;\\
0, & i-j=2\ell, \quad 0\le\ell\le k-1;\\
\binom{i-1}{j-2}Q_{\ell}, & i-j=2\ell-1, \quad 0\le\ell\le k-1,\quad j\ge2,
\end{cases}\\
Q_m&=\frac{2^{2m+2}\bigl(2^{2m+4}-1\bigr)}{(m+1)(m+2)(2m+1)(2m+3)}|B_{2m+4}|, \quad m\ge0,
\end{align*}
and $B_{2m+4}$ denotes the Bernoulli numbers generated by
\begin{equation*}
\frac{z}{\operatorname{e}^z-1}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty B_k\frac{z^k}{k!}=1-\frac{z}2+\sum_{k=1}^\infty B_{2k}\frac{z^{2k}}{(2k)!}, \quad |z|<2\pi.
\end{equation*}
As corollaries of the above Maclaurin power series expansion, we deduce the series expansions
\begin{equation*}
\ln(\tan x-x)=-\ln3+3\ln x-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{3^{2k}D_{2k}}{(2k)!}x^{2k}, \quad 0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
\ln\biggl(\frac{\tan x}{x}-1\biggr)
=-\ln3+2\ln|x|-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{3^{2k}D_{2k}}{(2k)!}x^{2k}, \quad 0<|x|<\frac{\pi}{2}.
\end{equation*}
Since the Bernoulli numbers can be expressed by closed-form formulas, so the sequence $D_{2k}$ is surely a closed-form formula.

About closed-form formulas for the Bernoulli numbers and about some conclusions on the tangent function, I would like to recommend the following papers.

References

1. Xue-Yan Chen, Lan Wu, Dongkyu Lim, and Feng Qi, *Two identities and closed-form formulas for the Bernoulli numbers in terms of central factorial numbers of the second kind*, Demonstratio Mathematica **55** (2022), no. 1, 822--830; available online at https://doi.org/10.1515/dema-2022-0166.
2. Feng Qi and Jacques Gelinas, *Revisiting Bouvier's paper on tangent numbers*, Advances and Applications in Mathematical Sciences **16** (2017), no. 8, 275--281.
3. Feng Qi and Bai-Ni Guo, *An explicit formula for derivative polynomials of the tangent function*, Acta Universitatis Sapientiae Mathematica **9** (2017), no. 2, 348--359; available online at https://doi.org/10.1515/ausm-2017-0026.
4. Feng Qi, *Derivatives of tangent function and tangent numbers*, Applied Mathematics and Computation **268** (2015), 844--858; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.amc.2015.06.123.
5. Jiao-Lian Zhao, Qiu-Ming Luo, Bai-Ni Guo, and Feng Qi, *Remarks on inequalities for the tangent function*, Hacettepe Journal of Mathematics and Statistics **41** (2012), no. 4, 499--506.
6. Chao-Ping Chen and Feng Qi, *A double inequality for remainder of power series of tangent function*, Tamkang Journal of Mathematics **34** (2003), no. 4, 351--355; available online at https://doi.org/10.5556/j.tkjm.34.2003.236.
7. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4248328
8. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4248341
9. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4248488
10. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4254493
11. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4254500
12. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4256893
13. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4256913
14. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4256915
15. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4656534

Comment: What is the use of this expansion?

Comment: At the beginning, I wish to find the series expansion of the function $f(x)$ for proving the function
$$
\frac{\ln\frac{3(\tan x-x)}{x^3}}{\ln\frac{\tan x}{x}}
=\frac{\ln\bigl[\frac{3}{x^2}\bigl(\frac{\tan x}{x}-1\bigr)\bigr]}{\ln\frac{\tan x}{x}}
$$
to be decreasing from $\bigl(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\bigr)$ onto $\bigl(1,\frac{6}{5}\bigr)$. Till now I am not successful to prove the monotonicity yet. The question at https://mathoverflow.net/q/444490 is an alternative try to prove the monotonicity which was guessed by a colleague last week.

Comment: This answer is too complicated for me to prove that the function \begin{equation}
\frac{\ln\frac{3(\tan x-x)}{x^3}}{\ln\frac{\tan x}{x}}
=\frac{\ln\bigl[\frac{3}{x^2}\bigl(\frac{\tan x}{x}-1\bigr)\bigr]}{\ln\frac{\tan x}{x}}
\end{equation} is decreasing from $\bigl(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\bigr)$ onto $\bigl(1,\frac{6}{5}\bigr)$. It would be more possible for sufficiently presenting a proof of the monotonicity if the determinant $D_{2k}$ is simplified in some form.

Comment: After getting the Maclaurin power series expansion of the function $f(x)$ in this answer, which, in my opinion, is much beautiful in mathematics, the next problem is: how to compute or expand the determinant $D_{2k}$ of a Hessenberg matrix (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessenberg_matrix) in a simple form?

Comment: Because all derivatives of analytic elementary functions are analytic and elementary, all analytic elementary functions have series expansions whose coefficients are of closed-form. I think so.

Comment: The decreasing property of the function \begin{equation} \frac{\ln\frac{3(\tan x-x)}{x^3}}{\ln\frac{\tan x}{x}} =\frac{\ln\bigl[\frac{3}{x^2}\bigl(\frac{\tan x}{x}-1\bigr)\bigr]}{\ln\frac{\tan x}{x}} \end{equation} has been proved at https://mathoverflow.net/a/444526 by Iosif Pinelis. The proposer of this decreasing property has also found out a proof for it. Even so, the problem at https://mathoverflow.net/q/444490 itself is still interesting, in my opinion.

Comment: You can reduce the matrix size from $2k \times 2k$ to $k \times k$ by rearranging the rows and columns, first the odd and then the even rows/cols. The resulting $2 \times 2$ block diagonal matrix has one trivial and one non-trivial determinant.

Comment: @FredHucht Good idea! I will do according to your good idea. Thank a lot!

Comment: Till now this is the best answer: the only one answer that gives a closed-form expression for the general term of the coefficients in the Maclaurin power series expansion of the function $f(x)$. Moreover, the determinant $D_{2k}$ is related to the Hessenberg matrices and appears much beautiful.

Comment: @zeraouliarafik Please read the question at https://mathoverflow.net/q/444525 and its answer at https://mathoverflow.net/a/444526.  How about your opinions? I think that we should pay our attention on mathematics and academics.

Comment: @FredHucht I cannot follow your idea to reduce the matrix size from 2k×2k to k×k. Could you please let me know more details and tell me the final result? Thank you!

Comment: As I said, rearrange rows and cols of $D_{2k}$, first the odd indices, then the even indices, e.g. for $k=4$ use indices $\{1,3,5,7,2,4,6,8\}$. Then, $D$ becomes a $2 \times 2$ block matrix, with zero diagonal. The upper right block is lower tridiagonal, with determinant $Q_0^k$, while the lower right block contains the desired result.

Comment: The answer at https://mathoverflow.net/a/444485/ and its proofs have been submitted for possible publication somewhere, while another two similar or closely-related papers have been formally published at https://doi.org/10.3390/math11143107 and https://doi.org/10.3390/axioms12070665.

Comment: This answer and related comments are included in the paper: Yue-Wu Li, Feng Qi, and Wei-Shih Du, Two forms for Maclaurin power series expansion of logarithmic expression involving tangent function, Symmetry, vol. 15 (2023), no. 9, Article 1686, 18 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.3390/sym15091686.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is obtained by introducing the Bessel functions to express
\begin{align}
f(x)&=\ln\left(\frac{\tan x-x}{x^3}\right)\\
&=\ln\left( \frac{\sin x-x\cos x}{x^3\cos x} \right)\\
&=\ln\left( \frac{J_{3/2}(x)}{x^2J_{-1/2}(x)} \right)
\end{align}
In a paper by [Dickinson](https://www.ams.org/proc/1954-005-06/S0002-9939-1954-0086897-8/S0002-9939-1954-0086897-8.pdf) a uniformly convergent series expansion is given for the logarithm of a Bessel function:
\begin{equation}
    \ln J_{\nu}(x)=\ln \left(\frac{(x / 2)^{\nu}}{\Gamma(\nu+1)}\right)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \ln \left(1-\frac{x^2}{j_{\nu, n}}\right)
\end{equation}
when $\nu>-1$ and $0<x<j_{\nu ,1}$ ($j_{\nu,n}$ is the $n$-th zero of the Bessel function of order $\nu$). Then,
\begin{align}
 \ln J_{\nu}(x)&=\ln \left(\frac{(x / 2)^{\nu}}{\Gamma(\nu+1)}\right)-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k+1}\frac{x^{2k+2}}{j_{\nu,n}^{2k+2}}\\
 &=\ln \left(\frac{(x / 2)^{\nu}}{\Gamma(\nu+1)}\right)-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2k+2}}{k+1}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{j_{\nu,n}^{2k+2}}
\end{align}
(all the summands in the convergent double series are positive and we may interchange the order of summation).
Thus
\begin{align}
 f(x)&=-2\ln x+\ln J_{3/2}(x)-\ln J_{-1/2}(x)\\
&=-\ln3 +\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2k+2}}{k+1}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{j_{-1/2,n}^{2k+2}}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{j_{3/2,n}^{2k+2}} \right)
\end{align}

The sum of inverse even powers of zeros of Bessel functions appears in problems involving the diffusion equation and a broad literature exists on the topic. The quantity
\begin{equation}
    \sigma(p,\nu)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{j_{\nu,n}^{2p}}
\end{equation}
is discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2911997/348034). A recent analysis can be found in a paper by [Jorge L. deLyra](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.0228.pdf) where a  general formula for certain linear combinations of these sums is given ; it can be used to derive the formulas for $\sigma(p, \nu)$ by purely linear-algebraic means.
The first values for $\nu=3/2$ are
\begin{align}
    &\sigma(1,3/2)=\frac{1}{10}\;;\;\sigma(2,3/2)=\frac{1}{350}\;;\;\sigma(3,3/2)=\frac{1}{7875}\\
    &\sigma(4,3/2)=\frac{37}{6063750}\;;\;\sigma(5,3/2)=\frac{59}{197071875}
\end{align}
while $j_{-1/2,n}=(2n-1)\pi/2$. Then
\begin{align}
 \sigma(k+1,-1/2)&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{j_{-1/2,n}^{2k+2}}\\
 &=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{2}{(2n-1)\pi} \right)^{2k+2}\\
 &=\left( \frac{2}{\pi} \right)^{2k+2}(2^{2k+2}-1)\zeta(2k+2)\\
 &=(2^{2k+2}-1)\frac{2^{2k+1}}{(2k+2)!}|B_{2k+2}|
\end{align}
Latter identity is obtained expressing the Zeta function at even values in terms of the Bernoulli numbers.
Finally,
\begin{align}
 f(x)&=-\ln3 +\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2k+2}}{k+1}\left(\sigma(k+1,-1/2)-\sigma(k+1,3/2)\right)\\
 &=-\ln3 +\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2k+2}}{k+1}\left((2^{2k+2}-1)\frac{2^{2k+1}}{(2k+2)!}|B_{2k+2}|-\sigma(k+1,3/2)\right)
\end{align}
which leads to the same first terms as in the expansion given by other users.

Comment: This answer surely gives a Maclaurin power series expansion of the function $f(x)$. Regrettably, its coefficients aren't of closed-form, since $\sigma\bigl(k+1,\frac32\bigr)$ isn't of closed-form. What I emphasized is that the coefficients are of closed-form. The answer at https://mathoverflow.net/a/444485 is still the best one, although it was voted down by somebodies.

Comment: Comparing this answer with the one at https://mathoverflow.net/a/444485 results in $$\sigma\biggl(k,\frac32\biggr)=\frac{(2^{2k}-1)2^{2k-1}|B_{2k}|+3^{2k}k D_{2k}}{(2k)!}$$ for $k\ge1$. This means that the sequence $\sigma\bigl(k,\frac32\bigr)$ for $k\ge1$ can be expressed by a closed-form formula, not an infinite series. Therefore, if one can directly find a closed-form expression for $\sigma\bigl(k,\frac32\bigr)$, this answer will be perfect.

Comment: Let $j_{\nu,n}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ denote the zeros of $\frac{J_\nu(z)}{z^{v}}$, where
\begin{equation*}
J_\nu(z)=\biggl(\frac{z}2\biggr)^\nu\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n(z/2)^{2n}}{n!\Gamma(\nu+n+1)}, \quad z\in\mathbb{C}
\end{equation*}
is the Bessel function of the first kind and $\nu\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{-1,-2,\dotsc\}$ is called the order of $J_\nu(z)$.
The Bessel zeta function is defined by
\begin{equation*}
\zeta_\nu(q)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{j_{\nu,n}^q}, \quad q>1.
\end{equation*}
I think that the quantity $\sigma(p,\nu)=\zeta_\nu(2p)$.

Comment: If $\sigma(p,\nu)=\zeta_\nu(2p)$ is true, then the quantity $\sigma(p,\nu)$ has a closed-form expression
\begin{equation}
\sigma(k,\nu+1)=\zeta_{\nu+1}(2k)
=(-1)^{k+1}\frac{[\Gamma(\nu+2)]^{2k+1}}{(2k)!}
\begin{vmatrix}
P_{2k+1,1}(\nu) & Q_{2k+1,2k}(\nu)
\end{vmatrix}_{(2k+1)\times(2k+1)}
\end{equation}
for $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\nu\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{-1,-2,\dotsc\}$.
For more details, please refer to my paper at https://doi.org/10.32604/cmes.2021.016431. Then this answer is perfect: the coefficients in the series expansion are closed-form expressions.

Comment: In the above paper, we also have
$$
\sigma(k,\nu)=\zeta_{\nu}(2k)
=\frac{(-1)^{k+1}\nu}{(2k)!}
\begin{vmatrix}
\frac{1}{(\nu)_0} & \frac{1}{(\nu+1)_0} & \dotsm & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & \dotsm& 0 & 0\\
\frac{1}{2(\nu)_1} & \frac{1}{2(\nu+1)_1} & \dotsm & 0 &0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
\frac{(2k-3)!!}{2^{k-1}(\nu)_{k-1}} & \frac{(2k-3)!!}{2^{k-1}(\nu+1)_{k-1}} &\dotsm & \frac{1}{(\nu+1)_0} & 0\\
0 & 0 & \dotsm & 0 & \frac{1}{(\nu+1)_0}\\
\frac{(2k-1)!!}{2^{k}(\nu)_k} & \frac{(2k-1)!!}{2^{k}(\nu+1)_k} & \dotsm & \binom{2k}{2k-2}\frac{1}{2(\nu+1)_1} & 0
\end{vmatrix}.
$$

Comment: This answer and related comments are included in the paper: Yue-Wu Li, Feng Qi, and Wei-Shih Du, Two forms for Maclaurin power series expansion of logarithmic expression involving tangent function, Symmetry, vol. 15 (2023), no. 9, Article 1686, 18 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.3390/sym15091686.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the series coefficients of
\begin{align}
f(x)&=\log[3x^{-3}(\tan x-x)] \tag{1a}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f^{(n)}(0) \frac{x^n}{n!} \tag{1b}\\
&=\frac{2 x^2}{5}+\frac{43 x^4}{525}
+\frac{524 x^6}{23625}+\frac{40897 x^8}{6063750}
+\frac{19393844 x^{10}}{8868234375} +O(x^{12}) \tag{1c}
\end{align}
according to
\begin{align}
f^{(n)}(0) = Y\left(\left[-(k-1)!,\quad-2^{k+2}\textstyle\binom{k+3}{k}^{-1}\cos(\pi k/2)E_{k+3}(0)\right]_{k=1}^n\right). \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{align}
Here, $Y()$ is the generalized Bell polynomial of the given $n\times2$ matrix, with Euler polynomials $E_k(x)$.
The corresponding Mathematica code reads:

```
Series[Log[3/x^3 (Tan[x] - x)], {x,0,10}]
Sum[BellY[Table[{-(k-1)!,-2^(k+2) Cos[Pi k/2] EulerE[k+3,0]/
    Binomial[k+3,k]},{k,n}]] x^n/n!, {n,1,10}]
```

Eq. \eqref{2} was obtained by writing $f(x)=g(h(x))$, with
\begin{align}
g(x) &= \log(1-x) = -\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k}, \tag{3a}\\
h(x) &= 1-\frac{3}{x^{3}}(\tan x-x) = -\sum_{k=1}^\infty 
3 \cos(\pi k/2) \frac{2^{k+3} E_{k+3}(0)}{(k+3)!} x^k, \tag{3b}
\end{align}
and using the Arbogast–Faà di Bruno formula ([https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faà_di_Bruno's_formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula),
http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BellY.html).

I guess there is no "closed-form" solution, as the involved polynomials become more and more complicated.

Comment: I am sure that there is a closed-form expression for the general term of the coefficients in the Mackaurin power series expansion of the functions mentioned in the question and its first comment by me. I am sure! I am working on it now.

Comment: How did you get the relation $f^{(n)}(0)=Y(…)$? Can you give a reference to it? I repeat again that I have found a closed-form expression. @FredHucht

Comment: I have added a short explanation to my answer. I am looking forward to your closed-form expression.

Comment: @FredHucht The function $h(x)$ can be expanded into $$h(x)=1-3\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^{2k+4}\bigl(2^{2k+4}-1\bigr)} {(2k+4)!}|B_{2k+4}| x^{2k}$$ for $|x|<\frac{\pi}{2}$. By the Faa di Bruno formula, we have $$f^{(n)}(0)=-\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(k-1)!}{[1-h(0)]^{k}} B_{n,k}\bigl(h'(0),h''(0),\dotsc,h^{(n-k+1)}(0)\bigr)$$ with $$h^{(2k+1)}(0)=0$$ and $$h^{(2k)}(0)=3\bigl(2^{2k+4}-1\bigr)2^{2k+4}\frac{(2k)!}{(2k+4)!}|B_{2k+4}|$$ for $k\ge0$, where $B_{n,k}=Y_{n,k}$ is the partial Bell polynomials. Is it easy to compute $$B_{n,k}\bigl(h'(0),h''(0),\dotsc,h^{(n-k+1)}(0)\bigr)$$ for all $n\ge k\ge0$?

Comment: Is it easy to compute $$B_{n,k}\bigl(h'(0),h''(0),\dotsc,h^{(n-k+1)}(0)\bigr)$$ for all $n\ge k\ge0$? In theory, this quantity is computable, but, in practice, it is very difficult to handle it. I would like to recommend some papers at https://qifeng618.wordpress.com/2018/03/19/some-papers-on-explicit-formulas-of-special-values-for-the-bell-polynomials-of-the-second-kind for your reference.

Comment: @FredHucht Is the answer at https://mathoverflow.net/a/444485 a closed-form expression? I think it is also beautiful to some extent. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: @qifeng618 I don't think your determinant answer is more "closed-form" than my BellY answer, both are recursion relations. Btw, you can reduce the matrix size from $2k \times 2k$ to $k \times k$ by rearranging the rows and columns, first the odd and then the even rows/cols. The resulting $2\times 2$ block diagonal matrix has one trivial and one non-trivial determinant. Further, you should consider to vote up useful answers.

Comment: A determinant and a partial Bell polynomial BellY are both closed-form expressions, the concept of determinants is more popular than the concept of BellY in my mind, I understand determinants better than BellY, although I have published many articles related to BellY in recent years. I think your idea to reduce the order of $D_{2k}$ from $2k$ to $k$ is very nice! I will have a try to reduce the order. I remember that I have always been voting up useful answers.

Comment: @FredHucht I cannot follow your idea to reduce the matrix size from $2k\times2k$ to $k\times k$. Could you please let me know more details and tell me the final result? Thank you!

Comment: As I said, rearrange rows and cols of $D_{2k}$, first the odd indices, then the even indices, e.g. for $k=4$ use indices $\{1,3,5,7,2,4,6,8\}$. Then, $D$ becomes a $2 \times 2$ block matrix, with zero diagonal. The upper right block is lower tridiagonal, with determinant $Q_0^k$, while the lower right block contains the desired result.

Answer (score -2):

This is not a complete answer for your question but just a key idea, I have used the first terms evaluated [above](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/444321/what-or-where-is-the-series-expansion-of-the-function-ln-bigl-frac-tan-xx#comment1146999_444321) by @
David E Speyer i have got the following discrete plot:

[image]

Using Mathematica the inverse series of the first 10 terms given by the following formula

$$O\left(\left(\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}} \sqrt{x-\log \left(\frac{x^3}{3}\right)}\right)^{10}\right)+\frac{47503588337 \left(\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}} \sqrt{x-\log \left(\frac{x^3}{3}\right)}\right)^9}{1601901100800000}-\frac{107033 \left(\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}} \sqrt{x-\log \left(\frac{x^3}{3}\right)}\right)^7}{181104000}+\frac{271 \left(\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}} \sqrt{x-\log \left(\frac{x^3}{3}\right)}\right)^5}{30240}-\frac{43}{420} \left(\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}} \sqrt{x-\log \left(\frac{x^3}{3}\right)}\right)^3+\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}} \sqrt{x-\log \left(\frac{x^3}{3}\right)}.$$

I'm not sure if there is such closed formula for your series expansion, but one can use polynomial approximation  of the function $\tan(x)$ (second order) around $x=0$ and
using [Inverse Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_inversion_theorem) one can get closed form by means of trigonometric functions and gamma function as:
$$-3 i^n \Gamma (n) \left| x\right| ^{-n} \left(\cos \left(\frac{\pi  n}{2}\right)+i \sin \left(\frac{\pi  n}{2}\right) \text{sgn}(x)\right).$$

Comment: i claimed that no closed form ,just i apprximated the tan function arround 0 then i got the last formula using inverse fourier transform .you should know that is wasting of time to search for such closed form regarding your given function

Comment: I have obtained a closed-form expression for the general term of all coefficients in the Maclaurin power series expansion of the function $\ln\bigl(\frac{\tan x}{x}-1\bigr)$, or $\ln(\tan x-x)$, or $\ln\frac{3(\tan x-x)}{x^3}=\ln\bigl[\frac{3}{x^2}\bigl(\frac{\tan x}{x}-1\bigr)\bigr]$. So I think that your claim is wrong. @zeraoulia-rafik

Comment: Are you sure that your picture is correct?  Usually when Mathematica produces an image with a red background like that, it is indicating that there is an error in the code that produced it.