# Ask for a proof of an inequality involving the Bernoulli numbers

Tags: inequalities, sequences-and-series, special-functions, integer-sequences, bernoulli-numbers

Let $B_k$ be the Bernoulli numbers and let
\begin{equation}
T_k=\frac{2^{2k}}{(2k)!}|B_{2k}|, \quad k\ge1.
\end{equation}
Prove the inequality
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\frac{1}{k+2}\sum_{j=0}^{k+1}\bigl[\bigl(2^{2j+1}-1\bigr)T_{j+1}\bigr] \bigl[\bigl(2^{2k-2j+6}-1\bigr)T_{k-j+3}\bigr]} {\frac{1}{k+1}\sum_{j=0}^{k}[(2^{2j+1}-1)T_{j+1}] [(2^{2k-2j+4}-1)T_{k-j+2}]}>\frac{\bigl(2^{2k+8}-1\bigr)T_{k+4}} {(2^{2k+6}-1)T_{k+3}}
\end{equation*}
for $k\ge0$.

Comment: without a motivation this question seems arbitrary; do you have a proof yourself and is this a "challenge" or a way to advertize your findings? (like your earlier question https://mathoverflow.net/q/444321/11260) ?

Comment: If without a motivation, who can write out so a complicated but beautiful inequality? I cannot. Factually this inequality is a sufficient condition for proving the function
$$
\frac{\ln\frac{3(\tan x-x)}{x^3}}{\ln\frac{\tan x}{x}}
=\frac{\ln\bigl[\frac{3}{x^2}\bigl(\frac{\tan x}{x}-1\bigr)\bigr]}{\ln\frac{\tan x}{x}}
$$
to be decreasing from $\bigl(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\bigr)$ onto $\bigl(1,\frac{6}{5}\bigr)$. The question at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/444321 is also a try to prove the monotonicity which was guessed by a colleague last week. Till now we aren't successful yet.

Comment: Till now the best answer to the question at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/444321 is at https://mathoverflow.net/a/444485. However, the answer is still too complicated. It would be better if the quantity $D_{2k}$ is simplified in some form or to present a proof of the function \begin{equation}
\frac{\ln\frac{3(\tan x-x)}{x^3}}{\ln\frac{\tan x}{x}}
=\frac{\ln\bigl[\frac{3}{x^2}\bigl(\frac{\tan x}{x}-1\bigr)\bigr]}{\ln\frac{\tan x}{x}}
\end{equation} being decreasing from $\bigl(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\bigr)$ onto $\bigl(1,\frac{6}{5}\bigr)$.

Comment: It seems that this inequality for Bernoulli numbers is much, much harder to prove than  the monotonicity of the ratio of the two logarithmic expressions. The latter can be done rather easily using a l'Hospital-type rule for monotonicity -- see https://mathoverflow.net/a/444526/36721

Comment: @IosifPinelis Thank a lot.

Comment: See Remark 11 in the paper: Yue-Wu Li, Feng Qi, and Wei-Shih Du, Two forms for Maclaurin power series expansion of logarithmic expression involving tangent function, Symmetry, vol. 15 (2023), no. 9, Article 1686, 18 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.3390/sym15091686.