# On the monotonicity of the ratio of two logarithmic expressions

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, inequalities

According to [this comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/444490/ask-for-a-proof-of-an-inequality-involving-the-bernoulli-numbers#comment1147661_444490) and [this comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/444490/ask-for-a-proof-of-an-inequality-involving-the-bernoulli-numbers#comment1147671_444490), a positive answer to [this recent question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/444490/36721) (about Bernoulli numbers) would be sufficient to prove the following:

> $r:=f/g$ is increasing on $(0,\pi/2)$ from $5/6$ to $1$, where
> \begin{equation}
>     f(x):=\ln\frac{\tan x}x,\quad g(x):=\ln\frac{\tan x-x}{x^3/3}. 
> \end{equation}

However, the mentioned sufficient condition seems much, much harder to prove than the actually desired highlighted claim above. In the answer below, the highlighted claim will be proved, using a so-called l'Hospital-type rule for monotonicity.

Comment: This problem was original proposed by my colleague. Except the question at https://mathoverflow.net/q/444490, its answers, and comments, another question at https://mathoverflow.net/q/444321 and, especially, the answer at https://mathoverflow.net/a/444485, has something to do with this question. The original proposer of this problem has also found a proof by the monotonicity rule.

Comment: @qifeng618 : Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The values $5/6$ and $1$ for $r(0+):=\lim_{x\downarrow0}r(x)$ and $r(\frac\pi2-):=\lim_{x\uparrow\pi/2}r(x)$ are easy to get by the l'Hospital rule for limits.

It remains to show that $r=f/g$ is increasing on $(0,\pi/2)$.

Note that $f(0+):=\lim_{x\downarrow0}f(x)=0$ and $g(0+)=0$. Next, for real $t>0$ we have  $0<\arctan t<t$  and
\begin{equation}
G_1(t):=g'(\arctan t)\frac{(t-\arctan t) \arctan t}{3 + t^2}
=\arctan t-\frac{3t}{3+t^2}. 
\end{equation}
In what follows, by default, $t\in(0,\infty)$.

Next, $G_1(0)=0$ and $G'_1(t)=4 t^4/((1 + t^2) (3 + t^2)^2)>0$. So, $G_1>0$ (on $(0,\infty)$) and hence $g'>0$ (on $(0,\pi/2)$). So, by the l'Hospital-type rule for monotonicity given by [Proposition 4.1](https://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/images/157_05_JIPAM/157_05.pdf), it is enough to show that the "derivative ratio"
\begin{equation}
    r_1(t):=\frac{f'(\arctan t)}{g'(\arctan t)}=\frac{f_1(t)}{g_1(t)}
\end{equation}
is increasing (in $t\in(0,\infty)$), where
\begin{equation}
    f_1(t):=\frac{(t - \arctan t) (-t + (1 + t^2) \arctan t)}{1 + t^2}, 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    g_1(t):=\frac{t (-3 t + (3 + t^2) \arctan t)}{1 + t^2}.  
\end{equation}

Note that
\begin{equation}
G_2(t):=g_1'(t)\frac{(1 + t^2)^2}{3 + t^4}=\frac{t (-3 + t^2)}{3 + t^4} +\arctan t,  
\end{equation}
so that  $G_2(0)=0$ and $G'_2(t)=(8 t^4 (3 + t^2))/((1 + t^2) (3 + t^4)^2)>0$. So, $G_2>0$ and hence $g_1'>0$.
Also, $f_1(0+)=0$ and $g_1(0+)=0$.
So, by the same l'Hospital-type rule for monotonicity, it is enough to show that the second "derivative ratio"
\begin{equation}
    r_2(t):=\frac{f_1'(t)}{g_1'(t)}=\frac{f_2(t)}{g_2(t)}
\end{equation}
is increasing, where
\begin{equation}
    f_2(t):=\frac{t^2 (t + (-1 + t^2)\arctan t)}{3 + t^4}, 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    g_2(t):=\frac{t (-3 + t^2) + (3 + t^4) \arctan t}{3 + t^4}.  
\end{equation}
Next, $g'_2(t)=(8 t^4 (3 + t^2))/((1 + t^2) (3 + t^4)^2)>0$ and $f_2(0+)=0=g_2(0+)$.

So, using once again the same l'Hospital-type rule for monotonicity, we see that it is enough to show that the third "derivative ratio"
\begin{equation}
    r_3(t):=\frac{f_2'(t)}{g_2'(t)}
    =\frac{3 t + 6 t^3 - t^5 + (-3 + 3 t^2 + 7 t^4 + t^6) \arctan t}{4 t^3 (3 + t^2)}
\end{equation}
is increasing. Let
\begin{equation}
    r_{31}(t):=r'_3(t)\frac{4 t^4 (3 + t^2)^2}{(3 + t^4) (9 + 2 t^2 + t^4)}
    =\frac{t (-9 + t^2)}{9 + 2 t^2 + t^4} + \arctan t. 
\end{equation}
Then $r_{31}(0)=0$ and $r'_{31}(t)=(32 t^4 (3 + t^2))/((1 + t^2) (9 + 2 t^2 + t^4)^2)>0$, so that $r_{31}>0$ and hence $r_3$ is indeed increasing. $\quad\Box$

Comment: @YaakovBaruch : I am puzzled as to why you are puzzled. As is now made more explicit on this page, "the original question" was about Bernoulli numbers, not about the ratio of two logarithmic expressions.

Comment: @YaakovBaruch : Actually, the system itself explicitly prompts everyone to answer their own questions, to share their knowledge. I too do not see anything bad in doing so; rather, to the contrary. In this particular case, it seemed useful to familiarize more people with the  l'Hospital-type rules for monotonicity. On the other hand, doing so in response to a question about Bernoulli numbers did not seem fitting or as useful to me. So, I am still puzzled by your reaction.

Comment: @YaakovBaruch : Good to hear this. However, as I said, even in general, " the system itself explicitly prompts everyone to answer their own questions, to share their knowledge. I too do not see anything bad in doing so; rather, to the contrary."

Comment: @IosifPinelis I support you! I vote up your answer! I completely agree to your opinions! I don’t puzzle any! We should pay our attention on mathematics and academics, not on others.

Comment: @qifeng618 : Thank you!

Comment: @YaakovBaruch : I don't think appealing to authorities is a strong argument. There is also an ethical aspect here: When your criticisms of, or expressed doubts on, actions of someone (say A) are based on opinions of some other person(s) (say B) who you say is/are smarter than you -- and yet **you** question actions of A, then one might infer that you imply that B (and perhaps yourself as well) is/are smarter than A. Isn't it much more productive to just discuss the matter in hand?

Comment: @YaakovBaruch : Let me try to rephrase my latter comment. You said that some people (say B) were smarter than you, whatever that may mean. You also referred to a certain opinion by B that contradicts an opinion by some person A. What is the purpose of you saying **here** that B is/are smarter than you? The natural answer to this question seems to be that you want to say that, if B is smarter than **you**, then A must defer to the opinion by B. But why?

Comment: Previous comment continued: The natural answer to that seems to be that you are suggesting that B is smarter than A, because B is smarter than you and you are no less smart than A. So, is all that really needed?

Comment: @YaakovBaruch : Well, you used the word "smarter" -- again, whatever that may mean. But, I think, "smarter" is hardly the same as "more authoritative", or maybe I am totally confused about what means what. As for authoritativeness, I can again repeat here that "the system itself explicitly prompts everyone to answer their own questions, to share their knowledge".

Comment: @YaakovBaruch : It does not seem that the system makes such a difference, as it suggests right away, even before the question is posted, that the question be answered by the OP, to share the knowledge. I too do not see a difference; qifeng618 was right that the important thing is dissemination and acquisition of knowledge, before other considerations, procedural or not.

Comment: See Remark 10 in the paper: Yue-Wu Li, Feng Qi, and Wei-Shih Du, Two forms for Maclaurin power series expansion of logarithmic expression involving tangent function, Symmetry, vol. 15 (2023), no. 9, Article 1686, 18 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.3390/sym15091686.

Answer (score 3):

**Alternative proof**.

Let us prove that $r = f/g$ is strictly increasing on $(0, \pi/2)$.

We have
$$f'(x) = \frac{x - \sin x \cos x}{x\sin x \cos x} > 0$$
and
$$g'(x) = \frac{3x - 2x\sin^2 x - 3\sin x \cos x}{x\cos x (\sin x - x\cos x)} > 0.$$

Let
$$h(x) := \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}
= \frac{(x - \sin x \cos x)(\sin x - x\cos x)}{(3x - 2x\sin^2 x - 3\sin x \cos x)\sin x}.$$

Using $f(0) = g(0) = 0$ ($x=0$ is removable), we have
\begin{align*}
    r'(x) &= \frac{f'(x)g(x) - f(x) g'(x)}{g(x)^2}\\[6pt]
    &= \frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}
    \left(\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} - \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{g(x) - g(0)}\right)\\[6pt]
    &= \frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}
    \left(\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} - \frac{f'(\theta)}{g'(\theta)}\right)
\end{align*}
where $\theta \in (0, x)$ (Cauchy's MVT).

Thus, it suffices to prove that
$h'(x) > 0$ or
$$4\,{s}^{4}{x}^{3}+c{s}^{5}+10\,c{s}^{3}{x}^{2}-11\,{s}^{4}x-6\,{s}^{2}
{x}^{3}-3\,c{s}^{3}-9\,cs{x}^{2}+9\,{s}^{2}x+3\,{x}^{3}
> 0$$
where $c := \cos x, s := \sin x$.

Let
\begin{align*}
    c_1 &= 1-\frac12\,{x}^{2}+\frac{1}{24}\,{x}^{4}-{\frac {1}{720}}\,{x}^{6}+{\frac {1}{
            40320}}\,{x}^{8}-{\frac {1}{3628800}}\,{x}^{10},\\
        c_2 &= 1-\frac12\,{x}^{2}+\frac{1}{24}\,{x}^{4}-{\frac {1}{720}}\,{x}^{6}+{\frac {1}{
                40320}}\,{x}^{8}-{\frac {1}{3628800}}\,{x}^{10} + \frac{1}{479001600}x^{12},\\
    s_1 &= x- \frac16\,{x}^{3}+{\frac {1}{120}}\,{x}^{5}-{\frac {1}{5040}}\,{x}^{7}+{
        \frac {1}{362880}}\,{x}^{9}-{\frac {1}{39916800}}\,{x}^{11},\\
    s_2 &= x- \frac16\,{x}^{3}+{\frac {1}{120}}\,{x}^{5}-{\frac {1}{5040}}\,{x}^{7}+{
        \frac {1}{362880}}\,{x}^{9}-{\frac {1}{39916800}}\,{x}^{11} + \frac{1}{6227020800}x^{13}.
\end{align*}
Then
$c_1 \le c \le c_2$ and $0 < s_1 \le s \le s_2$.

It suffices to prove that
$$4\,{s}_1^{4}{x}^{3}+c_1{s}_1^{5}+10\,c_1{s}_1^{3}{x}^{2}-11\,{s}_2^{4}x-6\,{s}_2^{2}
{x}^{3}-3\,c_2{s}_2^{3}-9\,c_2s_2{x}^{2}+9\,{s}_1^{2}x+3\,{x}^{3}
> 0$$
which is true (a single-variable polynomial inequality).
(*Note*: $cs^5 - c_1 s_1^5 = c(s^5 - s_1^5) + (c - c_1)s_1^5 \ge 0$ and $cs^3 - c_1 s_1^3 = c(s^3 - s_1^3) + (c - c_1)s_1^3 \ge 0$.)

We are done.

Comment: Thank you for this answer.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Nice problem. And l'Hospital-type rule for monotonicity is interesting and helpful.

Comment: In my opinion, the essentiality of this answer is still using monotonicity rule, perhaps the monotonicity rule is proved by such an idea. Even so, I vote up this answer, because not everybody knows the monotonicity rule.

Comment: @qifeng618 Thanks.

Comment: See Remark 10 in the paper: Yue-Wu Li, Feng Qi, and Wei-Shih Du, Two forms for Maclaurin power series expansion of logarithmic expression involving tangent function, Symmetry, vol. 15 (2023), no. 9, Article 1686, 18 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.3390/sym15091686.

Comment: @qifeng618 Thanks for making reference to my answer! Your link shows "Error: DOI NOT FOUND". Alternatively, we can see your paper in [researchgate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/373438590_Two_Forms_for_Maclaurin_Power_Series_Expansion_of_Logarithmic_Expression_Involving_Tangent_Function).

Comment: The DOI address is registering right now. I think it will work on Monday. You can access via https://www.mdpi.com/2073-8994/15/9/1686.

Comment: @qifeng618 Yes, this link is ok.